# Finding the indices of all matches in a string, appending search term and indices to a dictionary.

Tags: python, string, list, search, dictionary

I think I have an infinite loop? I made a dictionary with search terms as keys and one index where those keys were found in my_string. I'd like to create a search_dict with a list of ALL matches in my_string listed as indices for each key as a search term.

My search_dict isn't populated except for one item which has millions of items.

```
my_string='Shall I compare thee to a summer\'s day?'
#string_dict has only a single index as a value where its key was found in my_string
string_dict={'a': 36, ' ': 34, 'e': 30, '': 39, 'h': 17, 'm': 29, 'l': 4, 'o': 22, 'e ': 19, 's': 33, 'r': 31, 't': 21, ' t': 20, 'e t': 19}

#I'd like search_dict to have all indices for key matches in my_string
search_dict=dict()
for key in string_dict:
    search_dict[key]=list()
for item in search_dict:
    start=0
    end=len(my_string)
    found=my_string.find(item,start,end)
    while start<end:
        if found>=0:
            search_dict[key].append(found)
            start=found+len(item)
            found=my_string.find(item,start,end)
        else:
            break
print search_dict
```

I've also tried the changes below. Still not sure why if my_string.find comes up -1 (not found) the loop isn't breaking for the next search key iteration.

```
        else:
            break
#with
        if found<0:
            break
```

Comment: Looking for code review?

Comment: I'm learning by doing so, a review might be helpful. I don't understand why it's looping forever.

Comment: Yeah you have an infinite loop. Look at the condition in the second `while` statement.

Comment: I tried replacing the second while statement but am still stuck...hrmph

Comment: Do you see why the condition you used above caused an infinite loop? What did you replace it with?

Comment: I am still not clear why the original while loop condition is infinite. I edited the post with some other attempts. Howerver, am not quite sure why if my_string.find comes up as -1 (not found) the loop isn't breaking to iterate to the next key

Comment: I think I see why now. There was no way for the condition found<0 to break the while condition. This is because the first while loop would be always true even if second while were false. Have I run into another loop issue with my updated code attempts?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry yeah I was misreading the code actually -- I forgot that `find` returns `-1` on failure. Now I see your real problem. For one of the items in your dictionary, `len(item)` will be zero! So `start` won't advance, and then when `find` runs again it will find that same item again; its `len` will still be zero, and `start` won't advance... but I'll leave it to you to find which item in the dictionary that is.

Comment: I see now! I thought the item at position 39 was a space, it's an empty string I assume. Now I have to figure out how that got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that if you're looking for substrings and not characters I think regex would work best.

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string='Shall I compare thee to a summer\'s day?'
>>> search_items = ['a', ' ', 'e', 'h', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'e ', 's', 'r', 't', ' t', 'e t']
>>> results_dict = {}
>>> for search_item in search_items:
...     results_dict[search_item] = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(search_item, my_string)]
... 
>>> for elem in results_dict:
...     print("%s: %s" % (elem, results_dict[elem]))
... 
a: [2, 12, 24, 36]
 : [5, 7, 15, 20, 23, 25, 34]
e: [14, 18, 19, 30]
h: [1, 17]
m: [10, 28, 29]
l: [3, 4]
o: [9, 22]
e : [14, 19]
s: [26, 33]
r: [13, 31]
t: [16, 21]
 t: [15, 20]
e t: [14, 19]
```

While it's not specified in your question the value in the results is the starting position of the substring.

Comment: I'm able to use this to search for keys in dictionaries as well as items in lists. Avoiding creating a list was a goal. This solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was found thx to @senderle - items in my dictionary with len=0 resulted in an infinite loop. I have inserted a condition to fix this. @Slick offered the best solution to the problem

```
my_string='Shall I compare thee to a summer\'s day?'
string_dict={'a': 36, ' ': 34, 'e': 30, '': 39, 'h': 17, 'm': 29, 'l': 4, 'o': 22, 'e ': 19, 's': 33, 'r': 31, 't': 21, ' t': 20, 'e t': 19}

search_dict=dict()
for key in string_dict:
    search_dict[key]=list()
for item in search_dict:
    start=0
    end=len(my_string)
    found=my_string.find(item,start,end)
    while start<end:
        if found>=0:
            search_dict[item].append(found)
            start=found+len(item)
            if len(item)==0: #Fixed!
                break
            found=my_string.find(item,start,end)
        else:
            break
print search_dict
```